# using .toLocaleString() with variable storing integer works where using with direct number without storing in variable does not work

Tags: javascript

```
var number= +1000;
number.toLocaleString(); // output "1,000"
```

where

```
1000.toLocaleString() // output error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected` token
```

Comment: `(1000).toLocaleString();`

Comment: Dot(`.`) after `1000` is considered as `decimal-point` by JavaScript interpreter.. `1000.0.toLocaleStri‌​ng();` will work fine...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using Number methods on numbers like 1000, you should do it via **double** dot notation, e.g. `1000..toLocaleString()`

The reason to do it is that `1000.` interprets as number *with floating point*, thats why `1000.toLocaleString` fails

You can also go:

- `Number(1000).toLocaleString()`
- `(1000).toLocaleString()`
- `var number = 1000; number.toLocaleString()`

Comment: You learn something new everyday :)